# Magento Success Page Reverts to Default Theme

Tags: php, magento

We recently added a new extension to our site that adds multiple serial codes to a product (http://www.modifymage.com/instructions/serial-codes). Everything works great except when you try to purchase one of the items. It gives you a success page that uses the default theme.

Everything appears to be setup correctly in terms of the backend. I’ve already contacted the creator but I doubt they’ll provide any support.

Also, when I view source it says its referencing the right theme but when “Inspect Element” it tells me its using the default theme.

Any ideas? I’m thinking its a template issue but the success page uses the custom theme’s CSS.

Comment: Could you place a screenshot of your Admin->System->Configuration->Design. Expanded tabs: Package and Themes. Pretty often the problem is there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very unlikely to have anything to do with our extension. Our extension does not interact in any way with the front end themes.

In the Admin Panel, please first go to:

System > Configuration > General > Design

And check the settings under the Package and Themes sections. Please see this forum post for an example that presents itself exactly like the problem you are experiencing and how it was fixed:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/281457/

If that is all set up correctly, next try disabling the output of our extension and see if the problem goes away. You can do that here:

System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Module Output

Disable Mmsmods_Serialcodes. If this doesn't fix the problem, make sure the design file template/checkout/success.phtml is located in your design theme folder.

I hope that helps. If you are still having problems, or if you have any additional questions or concerns, please notify our support department once again.